# Don't include table in email if variable is empty - PHP

Tags: php, variables

I have html form and gets processed through php to send email. How can I hide tables and not to be included in email if variable ($ans01) is empty?

```
$message    .= '<table width="100%" rules="rows" style="border: 1px solid #0066cc;" cellpadding="5">';
$message    .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>This line is question and answer is below?</td></tr>";
$message    .= "<tr><td colspan='2' style='color:#0000FF;'><strong>" .$ans01. "</strong></td></tr>";
$message    .= "</table><br>";
```

Comment: just add if(!empty($ans01) condition top of table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add if with empty($ans01) equals to not. Code:

```
if (!empty($ans01)) {
    $message    .= '<table width="100%" rules="rows" style="border: 1px solid #0066cc;" cellpadding="5">';
    $message    .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>This line is question and answer is below?</td></tr>";
    $message    .= "<tr><td colspan='2' style='color:#0000FF;'><strong>" .$ans01. "</strong></td></tr>";
    $message    .= "</table><br>";
}
```

Good luck! :D